# HTTP code to return for unsupported PATCH

Tags: rest, http, dropwizard, http-patch

I am implementing a PATCH method on a dropwizard REST resource. 
Currently only a subset of the properties of the resource an be patched. And currently only the replace operation can be fulfilled.

Which HTTP code should I return if I see a `PATCH` request for a property/path that is not suppported? And what should I return if the unsupported `add` or `remove` operations are requested?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Which HTTP code should I return if I see a `PATCH` request for a property/path that is not suppported?

In this situation, the server should return [`405`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5) to indicate that a HTTP method is not supported by the target resource. Besides the status code, the server must return an [`Allow`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.4.1) header listing the supported methods for that resource:

> [**6.5.5.  405 Method Not Allowed**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5)
>
> The `405` (Method Not Allowed) status code indicates that the method
> received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not
> supported by the target resource.  The origin server MUST generate an
> `Allow` header field in a `405` response containing a list of the target
> resource's currently supported methods.

---

> And what should I return if the unsupported `add` or `remove` operations are requested?

I assume you mean [`add`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4.1) and [`remove`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4.2) operations from [JSON Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902), a JSON document that describes a sequence of operations to apply to a JSON document and is suitable to be used with the `PATCH` HTTP method.

So have a look a the [error handling](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2.2) section of the [RFC 5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789), the document that defines the `PATCH` HTTP method.

The situation described in your question is, in fact, an entity that cannot be processed by the server due to *semantic* reasons. So [`422`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2) is a reasonable choice, according to the [RFC 5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789):

> **Unprocessable request:**  Can be specified with a `422` (Unprocessable
> Entity) response  when the server
> understands the patch document and the syntax of the patch
> document appears to be valid, but the server is incapable of
> processing the request.  This might include attempts to modify a
> resource in a way that would cause the resource to become invalid;
> for instance, a modification to a well-formed XML document that
> would cause it to no longer be well-formed.  [...]

Also keep in mind the following recommendation from the same document:

> The entity body of error responses SHOULD contain enough information
> to communicate the nature of the error to the client.  The content-
> type of the response entity can vary across implementations.

The [RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807) defines document formats that can be used for reporting problems in HTTP APIs.

Comment: I realize my post can be interpreted as two questions. So I'll choose this as the answer.

The answer to the question I intended to ask is the second one, code 422. 

What I meant was that the PATCH verb is supported. But only for certain values of "path" in the json patch document (not url path). And only for "op:replace".

Answer (score 2):

My vote would be 405:

> 405 Method Not Allowed
>
> A request method is not supported for the
> requested resource; for example, a GET request on a form that requires
> data to be presented via POST, or a PUT request on a read-only
> resource.

Coupled with the suggestion that Cassio makes regarding providing enough information to describe the error.

Comment: `405` is not suitable for this situation once it will indicate that `PATCH` itself is not supported by the resource. Quoting the [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.5): _"The `405` (Method Not Allowed) status code indicates that **the method received in the request-line** is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource."_

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin - the OP said "Which HTTP code should I return if I see a PATCH request for a property/path that is not supported".  Isn't that exactly what you just quoted - "the method is not supported by the resource"?  Using a WEBDAV specific code seems the wrong way to go to me.

Comment: Turns out that the OP has **two** different questions (and I initially overlooked that). Your answer addresses the situation where `PATCH` is not supported by a particular resource. Hence I've upvoted your answer.